# Create anonymous enum value from a subset of all values

Tags: c#, autofixture

Let's say we have an enum type defined as:

```
enum Statuses
{
    Completed,
    Pending,
    NotStarted,
    Started
}
```

I'd like to make Autofixture create a value for me other than e.g. Pending.

So (assuming round-robin generation) I'd like to obtain:

Completed, NotStarted, Started, Completed, NotStarted, ...

Comment: Here is [one way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17117080/467754).

Comment: Unfortunately does not work: AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.ISpecimenBuilderComposer, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.

Comment: Which version of AutoFixture are you using? With AutoFixture 3, if you do `fixture.Create<Statuses>()` (where `fixture` is a `new Fixture()` instance) you will get each `Statuses` enum value in a round-robin fashion. You won't even need the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17117080/467754) I previously mentioned. If that doesn't work then it would be great if you can update the question with some code that reproduces what you describe...

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with 2.15.2.0...
Once I get home I'll check with the latest one. Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is with AutoFixture's `Generator<T>`:

```
var statuses = fixture
    .Create<Generator<Statuses>>()
    .Where(s => Statuses.Pending != s)
    .Take(10);
```

If you only need a single value, but want to be sure that it's not `Statuses.Pending`, you can do this:

```
var status = fixture
    .Create<Generator<Statuses>>()
    .Where(s => Statuses.Pending != s)
    .First();
```

There are other ways, too, but this is the easiest for an ad-hoc query.

Comment: I am interested in doing something similar but totally generically for any Enum type. I want to ignore any values based on string matches e.g. Unknown or Uninitialised. Is there a way to intercept the values returned by EnumGenerator?

Comment: @Schneider Complicated. New question, please.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Here is the qn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628519/how-to-exclude-certain-enumerations-from-all-enumeration-types

Comment: You can even do `fixture.Create<Generator<Statuses>>().First(s => s != Statuses.Pending)`