# Is there a simple way of creating an AutoFixture customization to restrict enum values?

Tags: c#, enums, customization, autofixture

I want to create a customization to restrict the values of an `enum` supplied by AutoFixture. The only examples I've been able to find so far use the imperative style (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957010/create-anonymous-enum-value-from-a-subset-of-all-values)).

Given the following `enum` definition:

```cs
public enum AnEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

I would like to restrict the values to `AnEnum.B` and `AnEnum.C`. I've tried some variations of the following code.

```cs
public class EnumCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public virtual void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<AnEnum>(
            c => c.FromFactory(() => new Generator<AnEnum>(fixture).First(e => e != AnEnum.A)));
    }
}
```

However, they all inevitably lead to an `AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath` exception. Without the customization AutoFixture will create a value of `AnEnum` as normal. Therefore, I think the problem lies with my attempts at customization rather than any circular references elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

OOTB, AutoFixture uses round-robin strategy to generate enum values. If you call `fixture.Create<AnEnum>()` multiple times, you receive a sequence of values such as `A`, `B`, `C`, `A`, `B` `...` etc.

There is a customization that uses default `EnumGenerator` and just ignores `C` values. It might look suboptimal, but it does the trick:

```
public class AnEnumEnumGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly EnumGenerator _builder = new EnumGenerator();

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var value = _builder.Create(request, context);
        if (value is AnEnum @enum && @enum == AnEnum.C)
        {
            return _builder.Create(request, context);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Now apply the customization and check the result:

```
fixture.Customize<AnEnum>(c => new AnEnumEnumGenerator());

Console.Out.WriteLine("result = {0}", fixture.Create<AnEnum>());
Console.Out.WriteLine("result = {0}", fixture.Create<AnEnum>());
Console.Out.WriteLine("result = {0}", fixture.Create<AnEnum>());
Console.Out.WriteLine("result = {0}", fixture.Create<AnEnum>());
```

Output:

```
result = A
result = B
result = A
result = B
```